# Why didn't the Doctor use regeneration energy to heal himself?

Tags: doctor-who

We see at the end of "Oxygen" that

> the doctor loses his eyesight.

Couldn't he have just used regeneration energy to heal himself? He had done so on other occasions, to heal others (River for example). Also in the last episode (Lie of the Land) he

> uses regeneration energy for no real reason (as he could just say to Bill this was all a trick after she shot him).

So, is this just an inconsistency?

edit: The question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159951/why-can-t-the-doctor-deal-with-his-condition) does not focus on the use of regeneration energy, but generally on anything that could

> heal the Doctor's eyesight, because he said there exist such things back in the TARDIS

The answer to the [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159951/why-can-t-the-doctor-deal-with-his-condition) was given before the last episode aired, so the part of the argument about the Doctor possibly not having "enough" energy to heal we know is not true (as the use of the energy for Bill to see is rather pointless, as Mr Lister said in the [comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161056/why-didnt-the-doctor-use-regeneration-energy-to-heal-himself#comment424891_161056)).
 In addition we know that he can use regeneration to heal himself as the 10th Doctor had done in Journey's End.

(The more I think of this, the more I believe it's just something they did not really think through)

Comment: Welcome to Dr Who, where nothing makes sense and it all works out in the end.

Comment: And Bill has never seen a Time Lord regenerate. She doesn't even know about regeneration, let alone such details as yellow stars coming out of sleeves. (The subject came up once, but the Doctor told her he would explain later.)

Comment: @elrond The other question more than covers why he didn't regenerate his eyes. In the case of Journey's End, the Doctor had taken a fatal blow.